# Do dreams improve upon memory and understanding by making the sensory experience MORE LIKE thought?

Tags: learning, memory, consciousness, dreams, thought

It is certainly a great fact/truth that the ability of thought to **describe** *or* reconfigure sensory experience is **ultimately** dependent upon the extent to which thought is similar to sensory experience. It occurs to me that dreams make thought **more like** sensory experience in general, thereby improving upon memory *and* **understanding**. Thoughts are invisible. The space in dreams is visible **and** invisible in fundamental equilibrium and balance, thereby making sensory experience maximally consistent with/similar to thought. This improves upon memory **and** understanding. There is no outsmarting the genius of dreams.

Dreams balance being and experience. Dream experience is possible/potential **and** actual **in balance**. Dreams balance conscious and unconscious experience. In dreams, we are relatively unconscious; and yet we are still conscious.

Thoughts are invisible. Do dreams improve upon memory and understanding by making the sensory experience **MORE LIKE** thought? This is a very important question which can improve upon our understanding of what dreams really are as well. Indeed, dreams fundamentally average **and** balance our *bodily/visual* experience. Notice that dreams involve balanced **and** maximum *middle strength* force/energy feeling/touch consistent with the experience of *middle distance* in/of space and *instantaneity*.

Consider that dream experience and waking experience are fundamentally related, and they are fundamentally linked; and they are separate experiences.

Comment: Your title is a question, but the body of your question seems like a statement. Can you improve the body of the question?

Comment: I improved the body of the question. Clearly, this is a very important question/discussion.

Comment: But you body still does not contain a question. Can you add a sentence with a question mark that you want answered? Right now your questions just reads as a series of statements.

Comment: This is a very important question.  That is certainly the case.